# django rest framework stop a save

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an api that mobile clients use to post images and videos. Now with mobile sometimes the client is able to make the post but not get the response so then when they are back in service they will make the same post and get a double post. To work around that problem, I'm setting a unique id on the client to send as a field with the post. So I post to something like

/api/post/

For that I am using a `serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer` with the `ViewSet` and it works well until you get a double post issue. I'm wondering if there is anyway either in the serializer or viewset to lookup that unique id and update it it if it's already been set and then stop and not do the save but return a valid 200 or 201

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could hash the files on the mobile device and send the hash with the POST request. You would then handle multiple uploads on the server side.

Another solution would be to make you mobile hit a url with GET to check what are the 5 latest files it has uploaded (hash only) before each upload, so you can spare further useless uploads for the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks.. right now i just send a reservation request and save the uuid of the row on the client and then it does a PUT until it gets back a 200/201 so I guess it'll just stick with that if there's not a cleaner solution